# Create a single Dictionary from a Nested Dictionary to Update MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, dictionary, mysql-python

I'm new to python and have run into an issue when trying to insert data from a nested dictionary into a MySQLdb. I have a dictionary that looks something like this, but much longer and can be variable in length.

```
d = {
    'Object_a': {
        'parameter_1': {
            'Cost': 12.00,
            'Markup': 23.4555
        },
        'parameter_2': {
            'Cost': 45.22,
            'Markup': 11.222,
            'Height': 44.33
        }
    },
    'Object_b': {
        'parameter_3': {
            'Length': 12.00,
            'Width': 23.4555
        },
        'parameter_1': {
            'Cost': 1.12,
            'Area': 4,
            'Volume': 16.72
        }
    }
}
```

I have been searching everywhere for a way to manipulate a nested dictionary into the form below. (I didn't know how to do a table so it's in csv style, sorry)

```
Object, Parameter, Cost, Markup, Height, Length, Width, Area, Volume 
Object_a, parameter_1, 12.00, 23.4555, , , , , , 
Object_a, parameter_2, 45.22, 11.222, 44.33, , , , , 
Object_b, parameter_3, , , , 12.00, 23.4555, , 
Object_b, parameter_2, 1.12, , , , , 4, 16.72
```

My Code to input the data into an SQL database is shown below:

Currently it takes a database name, table name, and dictionary given to it in another part of the program. Currently this checks if a table is created and if not will create one, if there is one created it will check which columns exist, if any are new it will add them and insert values into both new and existing columns.

I'm not so worried about any of this code, but my main concern is having no idea on how to pass one dictionary to this function to get to the desired form, or how to iterate through the above nested dictionary.

```
def tablecreate(cursor, tablename, dict):

    # Creates a list of keys to use as column names
    cols = list(dict.keys())

    # If warning occurs, no table exists so create one
    try:  
        sqlcheck = "SELECT 1 FROM {} LIMIT 1".format(tablename)
        cursor.execute(sqlcheck)
    except:
        sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s (ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY 
               KEY(ID))" %(tablename)
        cursor.execute(sql)
        # Creating the rest of the columns
        for i in range(0, len(cols)):
            sql = "ALTER TABLE %s ADD COLUMN %s VARCHAR (50)" % (tablename, 
                  cols[i])
            cursor.execute(sql)

    #Creates a list of new columns to be inserted into Table

    sql = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.columns WHERE 
           TABLE_NAME ='%s'" % (tablename)
    cursor.execute(sql)
    a = cursor.fetchall()
    b=[element for tupl in a for element in tupl]
    new_cols = [x for x in cols if x not in b]
    print (new_cols)

    for i in range(0, len(new_cols)):
        sql = "ALTER TABLE %s ADD COLUMN %s VARCHAR (50)" % (tablename, 
               new_cols[i])
        cursor.execute(sql)

    # Inserting values into the created columns
    placeholders = ', '.join(['%s'] *len(dict))
    columns = ', '.join(dict.keys())
    sql = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)" % (tablename, columns, 
           placeholders)
    cursor.execute(sql, dict.values())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not clear from your question what form you wanted the data in, but for manipulating the data, [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) is quite good at this sort of thing:

#### Code:

```
import pandas as pd

objs = []
for obj in d:
    for param in d[obj]:
        x = {
            'Object': obj,
            'Parameter': param,
        }
        x.update(d[obj][param])
        objs.append(x)
df = pd.DataFrame(objs).fillna('').set_index(['Object', 'Parameter'])
print(df)
print(df.to_csv())
```

#### Test Data:

```
d = {
    'Object_a': {
        'parameter_1': {
            'Cost': 12.00,
            'Markup': 23.4555
        },
        'parameter_2': {
            'Cost': 45.22,
            'Markup': 11.222,
            'Height': 44.33
        }
    },
    'Object_b': {
        'parameter_3': {
            'Length': 12.00,
            'Width': 23.4555
        },
        'parameter_1': {
            'Cost': 1.12,
            'Area': 4,
            'Volume': 16.72
        }
    }
}
```

#### DataFrame Results:

```
                     Area   Cost Height Length   Markup Volume    Width
Object   Parameter                                                     
Object_a parameter_2       45.22  44.33          11.222                
         parameter_1          12                23.4555                
Object_b parameter_3                        12                  23.4555
         parameter_1    4   1.12                         16.72
```

#### CSV Results:

```
Object,Parameter,Area,Cost,Height,Length,Markup,Volume,Width
Object_a,parameter_2,,45.22,44.33,,11.222,,
Object_a,parameter_1,,12.0,,,23.4555,,
Object_b,parameter_3,,,,12.0,,,23.4555
Object_b,parameter_1,4.0,1.12,,,,16.72,
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this ended up working for what I needed.